# What units should the height and width be for a PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing_Object?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm generating an Excel file in PHP using the PHPExcel library. I am placing an image in the worksheet.

```
$objDrawing->setWidthAndHeight(100,100);
```

What are the dimenions of the height and width of the drawing object (is it %, pixels, mm, cm)?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking, I believe that it's pixels, with an assumption of 72dpi when converting to Excel's rather quirky internal units.

Comment: In that case, I can't help... it's not an area of the code that I've worked on myself. The other option would be to assume that it's Excel's internal uom, as used to set column widths and row heights.

Comment: Apologies, you're right, it is pixels. Seems to be an issue in Excel 5, the image does not get resized correctly. Works in XLS though... any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

Comment: No ideas what might be the problem at the moment. As I said, images aren't a part of the codebase that I've been involved in much, but I'll try and find some time to take a look. You might want to post an issue on the PHPExcel issues board, just to give me a reminder.

Comment: Thanks for raising that on the PHPExcel issue log: that way, I won't forget about it

Answer (score 3):

> It's point.
>
> 1 point = 1/72 inches.
>    1 inch  = 72 points
>    1 point = 0.035 centimeters ( or .35 millimeters )